# What is the un-expanded version of "$_"?

Tags: shell

In bash/zsh we use `$_` representing the last argument to the previous command for later use, but this parameter contains the "expanded version" as documented. is there a thing that I can have un-expanded version of that? like in below example:

```
printf "%s\n" something{1..3}
```

I want to have access to un-expanded `something{1..3}` argument in the later command, not only `something3`.

doing this way also still adds only to very last argument not for all.

```
bash -c '
   printf "%s\n" "$@" && printf "%s\n" "$@"-add-something-more;
' _ something{1..3}
```

same in `zsh`, is there a way to to get that without `eval` trick that I don't preferer to use this way but want to show what exactly I want to have?

```
bash -c '
    eval printf "%s\\\n" "$@" && eval printf "%s\\\n" "$@"-add-something-more;
' _ 'something{1..3}'
something1
something2
something3
something1-add-something-more
something2-add-something-more
something3-add-something-more
```

Notes:

- Reading from the history is not an option as commands would executing within script and arguments would passing to the script by a user.
- I'm using `command1 "$@" && command2 "$@"<question-part>` syntax to execute `command2` only if `command1` was executed successfully.

Comment: In `zsh`: `fc -n -l -1 | awk '{ print $NF }'` (not an answer as I don't explain anything or say anything about `bash`; there are probably better ways too).

Comment: Ah, ok, that wasn't clear. Good.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to `insert-last-argument (M-., M-_)` but that can be used non-interactively?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, exactly and both to work in bash an zsh

Comment: But that and history expansion does that outside of the shell syntax (it adds text to a string which is later fed to the shell parser), doing it as part of the shell syntax wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reuse a list of args more than once, that's typically what (anonymous) functions or variables are for.

In `zsh`:

```
() {cmd1 "$@" && cmd2 "$@"} something{1..3}
```

```
l=(something{1..3}); cmd1 $l && cmd2 $l
```

To add the same string to each argument, use the `$^array` syntax:

```
$ () {echo $@; echo $^@-more} a{1..3}
a1 a2 a3
a1-more a2-more a3-more
```

(the `bash`/`ksh`/`zsh` equivalent would be `"${@/%/-more}"`).

To get an unexpanded version of `$_`, you could do something like:

```
TRAPDEBUG() last_cmd=($cur_cmd) cur_cmd=("${(z)ZSH_DEBUG_CMD}")
```

And then:

```
$ echo a{1..3}; echo $last_cmd[-1]
a1 a2 a3
a{1..3}
```

However note that the `DEBUG` trap is executed *before* each *sublist*, not *pipeline*, let alone *command*. So that wouldn't work for `echo a{1..3} && echo $last_cmd[-1]`. You'd need:

```
$ eval 'echo a{1..3}' && eval 'echo $last_cmd[-1]'
a1 a2 a3
a{1..3}
```